# How to make lxml's iterparse ignore invalid XML characters?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml

I have an XML with invalid characters.
LXML's XMLParser throws an exception on these invalid characters, but when I create XMLParser with **recover=True** option, it ignores the bad characters and works OK.

My question is how can I set similar flag for lxml's iterparse function?

**Reproduction:**

The broken XML (/tmp/z.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<items>
    <item>
        <B>Bad characters:</B>
    </item>
</items>
```

**NOTE:** There are two ASCII characters #31 (0x1F) after "Bad characters:" string, which I could not copy-paste here.

The parsing error of XMLParser:

```
fd = open('/tmp/z.xml')
parser = etree.XMLParser()
tree   = etree.parse(fd, parser)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2576, in lxml.etree.parse (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:22796)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1488, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:60390)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1518, in lxml.etree._parseFilelikeDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:60687)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1401, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFilelike (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:59658)
  File "parser.pxi", line 991, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFilelike (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:57303)
  File "parser.pxi", line 538, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:53512)
  File "parser.pxi", line 624, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:54372)
  File "parser.pxi", line 564, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:53770)
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: PCDATA invalid Char value 31, line 4, column 21
```

To ignore the bad characters I set **recover=True** and it works OK:

```
import lxml.etree as etree
fd = open('/tmp/z.xml')
parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
tree   = etree.parse(fd, parser)
etree.tostring(tree)

# OUTPUT:
<items>\n\t<item>\n\t\t<B>Bad characters:</B>\n\t</item>\n</items>'
```

With iterparse I get the same error again, but how can I make it ignore the bad characters?

```
fd = open('/tmp/z.xml')
it = etree.iterparse(fd, events=("start", "end"))
for e in it: print e
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "iterparse.pxi", line 498, in lxml.etree.iterparse.__next__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:73245)
  File "parser.pxi", line 564, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:53770)
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: PCDATA invalid Char value 31, line 4, column 21
```

Comment: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.lxml.devel/6235 read the last post. it seems that this is currently not possible with iterparse.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/14934854/407651, but that question has no accepted or upvoted answer. I suspect that the answer is what @pypat says.

Comment: @mzjn: Right, seems like it's the same question.

Answer (score 2):

`iterparse` also accepts the `recover` argument:

```
it = etree.iterparse(fd, events=("start", "end"), recover=True)
```

( Documentation: [lxml iterparse](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.iterparse-class.html) )

Comment: The `recover` option  was added to `iterparse()` in lxml 3.3.0: https://lxml.de/3.3/changes-3.3.0.html.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add document type header to your xml document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
```